# The result does not come from the correct branch

Tags: c, if-statement, networking, client-server

I implemented a client server application in C, I created the admin client with different options, GET_NO_CLIENTS return number of clients connected, GET_CLIENTS must to return the clients id. Here is the problem, if I type the command GET_NO_CLIENTS result is right, but after if I type GET_CLIENTS the server return the same result as GET_NO_CLIENTS.

Here is my code for client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int sockfd, portno, n;
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   struct hostent *server;

   char buffer[256];

   if (argc < 3) {
      fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
   }

   portno = atoi(argv[2]);

   /* Create a socket point */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

   if (server == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
      exit(0);
   }

   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   /* Now connect to the server */
   if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR connecting");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Now ask for a message from the user, this message
      * will be read by server
   */


   while(1)
   {
      char admin[2000] = "aDmIn007BO$$_";
      printf("Please enter the message: ");
      fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
      strcat(admin, buffer);
      /* Send message to the server */
      n = write(sockfd, admin, strlen(admin));

      memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
      if (n < 0) {
         perror("ERROR writing to socket");
         exit(1);
      }

      /* Now read server response */
      //bzero(admin, 256);
      n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);

      if (n < 0) {
         perror("ERROR reading from socket");
         exit(1);
      }
      else 
      {
         puts(buffer);
         memset(buffer, '\0', 256);
      }
      memset(admin, '\0', sizeof(admin));
  }
   return 0;
}
```

The server code:

```
/*
    C socket server example, handles multiple clients using threads
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    //write
#include <pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread

//the thread function
void *connection_handler(void *);
pthread_t tid;
int count_conn = 0, nr_admin = 0;
int clients_id[50];

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

   // printf("!!!!!!!%s", server.sin_addr.s_addr);

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
        count_conn++;
        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }


        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int connfd = 0;
    int read_size;
    int err;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *message , client_message[2000], file_name[2000], send_buffer[130000], command[200];
    int kk = 0;

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        clients_id[kk] = sock;
        //Send the message back to client
        if(strncmp(client_message, "GET_FILE ", 8) == 0)
        {
            for(i = 9; i < strlen(client_message); i++){
                file_name[j] = client_message[i];
                j++;
            }

            printf("Connection accepted and id: %d\n", sock);
            printf("Connected to Client: %s:%d\n", "127.0.0.1", 8888);

            FILE *fp = fopen(file_name,"rb");
            if(fp == NULL)
            {
                perror("File");
            }

            int bytes_read = fread(send_buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(send_buffer), fp);
            if (bytes_read == 0) // We're done reading from the file
                break;

            if (bytes_read < 0)
            {
                perror("ERROR reading from file");
            }

            //send file size to client
            write(sock, &bytes_read, sizeof(int));

            void *p = send_buffer;
            while (bytes_read > 0)
            {
                int bytes_written = write(sock, send_buffer, bytes_read);
                if (bytes_written <= 0)
                {
                    perror("ERROR writing to socket\n");
                }

                bytes_read -= bytes_written;
                p += bytes_written;
            }

            printf("Done Sending the File!\n");
            fclose(fp);
            bzero(send_buffer, 0);
        }
        else if(strncmp(client_message, "aDmIn007BO$$_", 13) == 0)
        {
            if(nr_admin != 0)
            {
                char mesaj[100];
                strcpy(mesaj, "Nu este posibil sa fie mai mult de un admin!");
                write(sock, mesaj, strlen(mesaj));
            }
            else
            {
                nr_admin++;
                for(i = 13; i < strlen(client_message); i++)
                {
                    command[j] = client_message[i];
                    j++;
                }

                if(strncmp(command, "GET_NO_CLIENTS", 14) == 0)
                {
                    char str1[15];
                    sprintf(str1, "%d", count_conn);
                    write(sock , str1, sizeof(char));
                    memset(str1, '\0', sizeof(str1));
                }
                else if(strncmp(command, "GET_CLIENTS", 11) == 0)
                {
                    char str[15];
                    int i = 0;
                    for(i = 0; i < strlen(clients_id); i++)
                    {
                        sprintf(str[i], "%d", clients_id[i]);
                        puts(str[i]);
                    }
                    write(sock, str, strlen(str));
                    memset(str, '\0', sizeof(str));
                }
                nr_admin--;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
        }

        memset(client_message, '\0', sizeof(client_message));
        memset(file_name, '\0', sizeof(file_name));
        kk++;
    }
    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        count_conn--;
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 'new_sock = malloc(1);  *new_sock = client_sock;' won't fit.

Comment: 'clients_id[kk] = sock;'.............kk++;' non-thread-safe update of global array and its index.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion, how to get clients id from server for print after in client ? OR how to change this sequence of code for correct result ?

Comment: 'n = read(sockfd, buffer, 256);' renders following 'puts' UB if all 256 bytes are read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in this part:

```
for(i = 13; i < strlen(client_message); i++)
{
        // command keeps getting appended because of j not being zeroed
        command[j] = client_message[i];
        j++;  // this is not local variable for this for-loop
}
```

and moreover this thing doesn't seem to be right

```
sprintf(str[i], "%d", clients_id[i]);
```

instead you should do `str[i] = clients_id[i];`

And yes be careful with `i`